# Searching the Google Container Registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I've been setting up my kubernetes cluster and I have been using the [Google Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/tools/container-registry) for storing images.

As a part of my setup I am building some tooling where I need to search the remote repository for images, including tags.

So my question is: 
**How do I search Google Cloud Registry for images?**

I've tried without luck to use `docker` cli to do the search:

```
$ docker search eu.gcr.io/project-101
Error response from daemon: Unexpected status code 403

$ gcloud docker search eu.gcr.io/project-101
Error response from daemon: Unexpected status code 403

$ docker login -e not@val.id -u _token -p mytoken https://eu.gcr.io
WARNING: login credentials saved in /Users/drwho/.docker/config.json
Login Succeeded

$ docker search eu.gcr.io/project-101
Error response from daemon: Unexpected status code 403

$ docker search eu.gcr.io/not-known
Error response from daemon: Unexpected status code 404
```

As you see I've tried a good deal of different approaches. The last option could be using the Google Storage Bucket API and search the file system "manually".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Docker clients through 1.7.0 only support unauthenticated search.  For example if you search for:

```
$ docker search gcr.io/google-containers/kube
NAME                                        DESCRIPTION   STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
google-containers/hyperkube                               0                    
google-containers/kube-apiserver                          0                    
google-containers/kube-controller-manager                 0                    
google-containers/kube-scheduler                          0                    
google-containers/kube-ui                                 0                    
google-containers/kube2sky                                0                    
google-containers/kubectl                                 0
```

I submitted a PR into 1.8.0 that will authenticate searches, and work similarly for private repositories.

Today the 403 (Forbidden) is because the Docker client isn't actually passing the authentication that is setup via `gcloud docker` or `docker login`.

**EDIT:** As a workaround, it isn't too bad to just CURL the endpoint:

```
$ curl -u _token:TOKEN "https://gcr.io/v1/search?q=QUERY" | \
    python -mjson.tool
```

You can generate `TOKEN` with `gcloud auth print-access-token`.

We support queries of the form `<project-id>[/image-substring]`, e.g. `google-containers/ube` would match `google-containers/kube2sky`.

Comment: Is it possible to do the search without the docker client then?

Comment: LOL, I was just editing to provide the workaround, see above.

Comment: Hehe, awesome :) I just tested it out though and with a minor problem with base64 not supporting `-w` on mac out of the way I got through to either this: `Access denied` when search for the project name or `Not found` when  searching for anything else. I've tested it both with a token generated for _server_ and one for _browser_.

Comment: I was able to just drop the `-w0` on my macbook, and it worked.  For generating the token, you should use: `gcloud auth print-access-token`.  Access tokens typically look like `ya29.{long string}`, so if it doesn't you might be using the wrong kind of token.

Comment: Great! That was the cause. I used the tokens made through the _cloud console_. Did not now about the `gcloud auth print-access-token` stuff. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: A bit simpler command you can use with curl is `curl -u _token:token https://eu.gcr.io/v1/search?q=search`. That will do the basic auth encoding for you :)

Comment: Great. Could you for reference give a link to the PR you submitted?

Comment: @mattmoor how would you search for a image with a specific tag? ie. I don't care if there's an image demo, if it's not tagged with 1.1.0

Comment: There is no way to tell from the search results, and there isn't really a natural way of asking that question thru the CLI search AFAIK.  I tried: ```$ docker search ubuntu:14.04
Error response from daemon: Invalid repository name (ubuntu:14.04), only [a-z0-9-_.] are allowed```

Comment: Note that our Web UI does support this.

Comment: How to list tags it has?               


        `curl https://gcr.io/google-containers/hyperkube/tags` is not working.

Comment: I had luck with curl and jq to view all tags - `curl -k -s -X GET https://gcr.io/v2/google_containers/kube-apiserver/tags/list | jq -r '.tags[]'`

Comment: Apparently, `gcloud` has new `alpha` commands for listing tags as well:
`gcloud alpha container images list-tags  gcr.io/google-containers/kube-apiserver`

Comment: gcloud container is now available in GA, so you should skip `alpha`:
`gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/google-containers/kube-apiserver`

Answer (score 19):

Strangely, gcr.io doesn't support search in any obvious way. Use https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/google-containers/GLOBAL to search.